# How do I Cast a string value formatted like "$400,000.88" to a decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to insert a string value that looks like money from one table to another table where the column type is decimal(18,2).  I have tried code that looks like: `CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(d.Cost,',',''),'$','') AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS 'Cost'`
but get the error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: your probably getting a cast error because you have a d.Cost value in your data set that is blank or NULL. Your code needs to handle this. if null then blank. if blank then 0 .. something like that

Comment: This is why you shouldn't have formatted strings in your database -- because once you format them, they're (expletive) unusable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good idea to store formatted values in your database, but this problem is easy to workaround.

The reason you can't cast it into *Decimal* is because currently it's a *Varchar*. So first cast it in *Money* and then you can cast it into something else.

This works in Sql Server:

```
select cast(cast('$400,000.88' as money) as decimal(10,2))
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks so much. It makes sense that once it is cast to money which is numeric, it can be cast to other numberic datatypes.

Comment: Minor nitpick, you can cast to decimal from varchar, it just has to be a valid conversion.  Commas and currency symbols prevent a valid conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
CAST(CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(d.Cost,',',''),'$','') AS Float) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS 'Cost'
```

Comment: I should have explained earlier this is sql server. I tried to cast as float but get "Error converting data type varchar to float."
The data is from an uploaded excel spread sheet so I made the table that field lands into varchar. I may need to make the column decimal and clean out the "$" and "," prior to landing in the table.

Comment: I have found a solution that I am  not sure is the best but I will be going with for now. I will have the user upload their excel file with the "cost" column formatted as number not currency.

Answer (score 0):

Thomas's comments made me rethink the work flow for the user. I was wanting the upload of excel files to be flexible but allowing to upload the 'cost' column as currency was causing the problem. They will be required to format the column in the excel file as number not currency.